# Globally Shared Substitution with Dice Dependency Injection

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I'm trying to get familiar with Dice Dependency Injection but I'm failing with my first trials.

I want to tell Dice that each class depending on `MyInterface` should get an instance of `MyInterfaceImpl` so I'm evaluating this with `MyClass`.

Obviously I'm missing some detail with the rules in Dice.

This is my example code:

```
<?php
namespace Example;

require("vendor/autoload.php");

interface MyInterface {}

class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {}

class MyClass {
    public function __construct(MyInterface $i) {}
}

class MyOtherClass {
    public function __construct(MyInterface $i) {}
}

$dice = new \Dice\Dice();

$rule = new \Dice\Rule();
$rule->shared = true;
$rule->substitutions['Example\\MyInterface'] = new \Dice\Instance('Example\\MyInterfaceImpl');
$dice->addRule('Example\\MyClass', $rule);

$instance = $dice->create("Example\\MyClass");
$instance = $dice->create("Example\\MyOtherClass");
```

The output of running this code is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot instantiate interface Example\MyInterface in …/vendor/tombzombie/dice/Dice.php on line 38
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() …/dicetest.php:0
PHP   2. Dice\Dice->create() …/dicetest.php:26
PHP   3. Dice\Dice->Dice\{closure}() …/vendor/tombzombie/dice/Dice.php:43
PHP   4. Dice\Dice->Dice\{closure}() …/vendor/tombzombie/dice/Dice.php:38
PHP   5. Dice\Dice->create() …/vendor/tombzombie/dice/Dice.php:70
PHP   6. Dice\Dice->Dice\{closure}() …/vendor/tombzombie/dice/Dice.php:43
```

If you want to run the code you need to configure composer with `"require": {"tombzombie/dice": "dev-master"}`.

The rule has to get the name of the class I want to instantiate as shown in the example code

But still I can't use this substitution globally unless I also add the same rule for `MyOtherClass`, but this would not be *globally* as I'd expect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dice provides a [default rule](https://r.je/dice.html#example3-6) for defining e.g. substitutions which are used if any class is instantiated. It is denoted by an asterisk `*`:

```
<?php
namespace Example;

require("vendor/autoload.php");

interface MyInterface {}

class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {}

class MyClass {
    public function __construct(MyInterface $i) {}
}

class MyOtherClass {
    public function __construct(MyInterface $i) {}
}

$dice = new \Dice\Dice();

$rule = new \Dice\Rule();
$rule->shared = true;
$rule->substitutions['Example\\MyInterface'] = new \Dice\Instance('Example\\MyInterfaceImpl');
$dice->addRule('*', $rule);

$instance = $dice->create("Example\\MyClass");
$instance = $dice->create("Example\\MyOtherClass");
```